# How to count textarea with variable in spring form?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jsp, spring-form

I'm using spring mvc with mysql to make quiz web application and i'm stuck at trying to make form for administrator to add answers correctly when creating a quiz.

In my form i have four possible answers and i can insert everything into mysql, but i always get all four answers together in my text column and i want to separate them.

For example in mysql table:

id | text | correct | questionId

1 |ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4| true | 1

and i need only 1 answer in each row.

My jsp and controller code:

```
<s:url var="url_create_answer" value="/admin/createAnswer"/>
                <f:form action="${url_create_answer}" commandName="command">
                    <table border="1">
                        <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="4">

                            <tr>
                                <td>Answer${i}</td>
                                <td><f:textarea rows="5" cols="100"  path="answer.text" placeholder="text answer ${i}"/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Is Correct?</td>
                                <td><f:radiobutton  path="answer.correct" value="${i}" /></td>
                            </tr>                                
                        </c:forEach>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" align="right"><button>Create</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>                          
                    </table>                                
                </td>               
            </tr>
        </f:form>




@Controller
public class CreateAnswerController {

@Autowired
AnswerService answerService;

@RequestMapping(value = "admin/addAnswer", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String createQuestionForm(Model m) {
    AnswerCommand cmd = new AnswerCommand();
    m.addAttribute("command", cmd);
    return "addAnswer"; // JSP view
}

@RequestMapping(value = "admin/createAnswer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleCreateAnswer(@ModelAttribute("command") AnswerCommand cmd,BindingResult result, Model m,HttpSession session) {

    for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
    try {           
        Integer questionId = (Integer)(session.getAttribute("questionId"));            
        cmd.getAnswer().setQuestion_id(questionId);
        if(!cmd.getAnswer().getText().equals(""))
            if(cmd.getAnswer().getCorrect() == i){
                cmd.getAnswer().setCorrect(1);
                int answerId = answerService.createAnswer(cmd.getAnswer()); 
            }else{
                cmd.getAnswer().setCorrect(0);
                int answerId = answerService.createAnswer(cmd.getAnswer()); 
            }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        m.addAttribute("err", "Could not add question to quiz");
        return "addAnswer";
    }
    }
    return "redirect:addQuestion"; //JSP view
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can store answers with some unique separator like @$%! and when you retrieve it from database, you can split it and choose the suitable answer and use it.

Comment: I need to have them in separated rows because i also need to have true of false value in mysql for every answer.